# cannot open .mexa64 file format in MATLAB for Ubuntu

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to open a mex file at Ubuntu(.mexa64) and I have the builtin gcc of ubuntu.I can check that by typing 'gcc -v' at terminal.
But MATLAB cannot open this file.
Any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "open"? executing it? which errors do you get?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the correct thing to do but I right click on it and click run then:Error using file
file id ...

Comment: quoting the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/call-mex-file-functions.html): " To call a MEX-file, use the name of the file, without the file extension." you have to do this from within MATLAB!

Comment: to complement @m.s. answer, mex files are supposed to be called inside matlab as if they were matlab functions.

Comment: You can't "open" the file.  That is all compiled code.  You need to run the MEX file in MATLAB as if it were an actual function you'd call.